# Selectable RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

My English isn't the best but I hope you understand, I'm new at developing android apps, and at the moment I have a recycler view, that its filled with a `WebService`, I'm trying to make these recyclerview items selectable, at this point I've tried:

- [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter)
- [And this tutorial](https://enoent.fr/blog/2015/01/18/recyclerview-basics/)

With the `flexibleAdapter` I have the Item and the Fragment but it doesn't work at all. with the second one, I've tried with other fragment and it can listen to the clicks but there is a listener that is used for starting a selection mode and this selection mode is controlled with an active mode and this action mode isn't working soo, don't know what to do right now

This is my code with the "FlexibleAdapter".
My "Item" object

```
public class TrazaFlex extends AbstractFlexibleItem<TrazaFlex.ViewHolderTrazaFlex> {
   public TrazaFlex(){

    }

...
...
   @Override
    public void bindViewHolder(FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible> adapter, ViewHolderTrazaFlex holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
        holder.mTitle.setText(nombreTraza);
        // Title appears disabled if item is disabled
        holder.mTitle.setEnabled(isEnabled());

        Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
        Drawable drawable = DrawableUtils.getSelectableBackgroundCompat(
                Color.WHITE, Color.parseColor("#dddddd"), // Same color of divider
                DrawableUtils.getColorControlHighlight(context));
        DrawableUtils.setBackgroundCompat(holder.itemView, drawable);
    }

   public class ViewHolderTrazaFlex extends FlexibleViewHolder {
        public TextView mTitle;

        public ViewHolderTrazaFlex(View view, FlexibleAdapter adapter) {
            super(view, adapter);
            mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_nombre_traza);
        }
    }
```

And this is my fragment:

```
public class TrazaFragment extends Fragment implements ActionMode.Callback, FlexibleAdapter.OnItemClickListener, FlexibleAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener {

    ArrayList<Traza> listaTrazas;
    RecyclerView recyclerTrazas;
    View vista;

    private FlexibleAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionMode mActionMode;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setTitle("Trazas");
        vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_traza, container, false);
        listaTrazas = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerTrazas = (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTrazas);
        recyclerTrazas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        GetTrazas mAttempTraza = new GetTrazas();
        mAttempTraza.execute((Void) null);

        return vista;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.selected_menu, menu);
        mAdapter.setMode(Mode.MULTI);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mAdapter.setMode(Mode.IDLE);
        mActionMode = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        if (mActionMode != null && position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            // Mark the position selected
            toggleSelection(position);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"OnItemLongClick ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"OnItemLongClick ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Handle the item click listener
            // We don't need to activate anything
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(int position) {
        if (mActionMode == null) {
            getActivity().startActionMode(this);
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"OnItemLongClick ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        toggleSelection(position);
    }

    /**
     * Toggle the selection state of an item.
     * If the item was the last one in the selection and is unselected, the ActionMode
     * is stopped.
     */
    private void toggleSelection(int position) {
        // Mark the position selected
        mAdapter.toggleSelection(position);

        int count = mAdapter.getSelectedItemCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            mActionMode.finish();
        } else {
            setContextTitle(count);
        }
    }
    private void setContextTitle(int count) {
        mActionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(count) + " " + (count == 1 ?
                "Action Selected One" :
                "Action Selected Many"+count));
    }


    public class GetTrazas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
      //connects to service and get json
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {


            recyclerTrazas = (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTrazas);
////            recyclerTrazas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            List<IFlexible> listaTrazasFlex = getDatabaseList();
            FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible> adapterFlexTraza = new FlexibleAdapter<>(listaTrazasFlex);
            recyclerTrazas.setAdapter(adapterFlexTraza);

        }
        public List<IFlexible> getDatabaseList() {
            //connects to json and returns a list

                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {

            }
            return list;
        }
    }

}
```

- Does the ActionMode can only be used in activity?
- Where and how can I set the listener for the adapter to make the items clickable
- Can someone explain to me how does it work the recyclerview in a fragment and how does it work the action mode bar at the top when starting a selection mode

Comment: do you want the RecylerView to be clickable or the items of the RecyclerView?

Comment: Sorry, the items in the recyclerview